# How do I run my script without getting ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-import

I have project layout something like this:

`kicksbot/kicksbot/*source files*`
`kicksbot/kicksbot/bot.py` - the main script
`kicksbot/tests/*test source files*`

I'm trying to run it from the project root using:
`python kicksbot/bot.py`

But I get the following error

```
File "kicksbot/bot.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kicksbot.basic_handlers import BasicHandlers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kicksbot'
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: @sammy yes, it does, thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)